# How to implement many to many relationship using Oracle Apex 3.2 form?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a many to many relationship on 2 tables.

table1 - primary key = link_id + other fields

table2 - primary key = category_id + other fields

table3 - primary key = link_id + category_id (no other fields in the table)

I'm just wondering how can I implement this on Apex 3.2.

The 2nd table is just the possible categories that can apply to a link. (e.g. Training, Prevention, Mental health and etc). 1 link can have many categories attached to it.

I'm hoping all the possible categories will appear on the screen as a checkbox and then when I open a link record (e.g. Mental health and training categories are assigned to the record), the corresponding checkbox will be automatically ticked. And of course, the ability to tick/untick checkboxes as I please and save/update the record.

I've looked at examples but I cannot find them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a report on your table1 and a form on your table2 and 3. In your report you need to add an edit_link which will set your form with the correct link_id. For your category form items you can set the attribute "Display as" to "Checkbox".